# How can I find out whether the user pressed the Call or the Cancel button when making a call from my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl, uiapplication

I need to return to my app after making a call from my app, so I use this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://123-4567-890"]; 
[[UIApplication  sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

When the user presses a button to execute this code, an alert is shown with 2 buttons, "Call" and "Cancel".

How can I find out if the user pressed the "Call" button?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but you could identify that "call" was pressed instead of "cancel" by listening for the UIApplicationSuspendedNotification (you'd have to add some logic to ignore this event when someone pushed the 'home' key, or was accepting an incoming call... maybe by adding/removing the observer around the logic where the phone number is being presented):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(suspended:) name:@"UIApplicationSuspendedNotification" object:nil];

-(void)suspended:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Suspended");
}
```

Comment: exactly what I needed except that is seems your notification doesnt exist anymore in iOS6 use: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification

Comment: @NicolasManzini: I tried UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, but seems not working in iOS8

Answer (score 13):

Here is an **iOS 10+** solution for **Swift 4.2**, tested with iOS 12 that detects both the Cancel and the Call button.

**Don't forget to import CallKit and conform your class to `CXCallObserverDelegate`!**

```
let callObserver = CXCallObserver()

var didDetectOutgoingCall = false

func showCallAlert() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "tel:+36201234567"),
        UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
            return
    }

    callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)

    didDetectOutgoingCall = false

    //we only want to add the observer after the alert is displayed,
    //that's why we're using asyncAfter(deadline:)
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { [weak self] success in
        if success {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                self?.addNotifObserver()
            }
        }
    }
}

func addNotifObserver() {
    let selector = #selector(appDidBecomeActive)
    let notifName = UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: selector, name: notifName, object: nil)
}

@objc func appDidBecomeActive() {
    //if callObserver(_:callChanged:) doesn't get called after a certain time,
    //the call dialog was not shown - so the Cancel button was pressed
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) { [weak self] in
        if !(self?.didDetectOutgoingCall ?? true) {
            print("Cancel button pressed")
        }
    }
}

func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
    if call.isOutgoing && !didDetectOutgoingCall {
        didDetectOutgoingCall = true

        print("Call button pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: this is perfect answer.

Comment: @ShrikantPhadke Please let me know if apple approve this while we will upload on store?

Comment: @NikunjJadav As far as I know, it's OK to use, as it's not using private APIs.

Comment: @NikunjJadav. Yes, Apple will approve it. Because CallKit is apple's Framework.

Comment: This is a great answer but how could this work if you're making a USSD call? Let's say you want to use this string: URL(string: "tel://*134*36201234567#") Please note the /*134* and # additions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(suspended:) name:@"UIApplicationSuspendedNotification" object:nil];
```

The above code by @J Saprio works absolutely fine. Before it suspends the Application `NSNotificationCenter` call `UIApplicationSuspendedNotification`. Once you click the "call" it will execute the `(suspended:)` method. Here the catch is, every time you call `NSNotificationCenter` method it will give a call to `(suspended:)` with the increment of one. Solution is to remove the observer for `NSNotificationCenter`. Following is the snippet for it. It will help you to execute the following method only once.

```
-(void)suspended:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Suspended");
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIApplicationSuspendedNotification" object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per **iOS terms** it is not possible. when completing the call can't redirect to Application.

In Jailbroken Phones only it's possible.

Comment: It is possible, you use safari API, which helps you to return back where you left.

Answer (score 1):

When application executes above code, it will exit current application & navigate to call application of iPhone. So, it is not possible for the application to identify whether the user has pressed call or cancel. Hope,it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,I deal with this issue as follows:

in `-(void)viewDidLoad` add the following :

```
NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[center addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                    object:nil
                     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
 {
     // use instance flag to know
     if (self.isBeginCallPhone)
     {
         //do some thing
         self.isBeginCallPhone = NO;
     }
 }];
```

Do not forget：

```
- (void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
  }
```