# ios: how to detect user cancel dial a phone number

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out if user pressed call or cancel button when making call from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743344/how-to-find-out-if-user-pressed-call-or-cancel-button-when-making-call-from-my-a)

I can dial a phone number in ios using following code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

since there will show an alert view after run this code, how can I detect whether user press Cancel button or Call button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't directly possible without jailbreaking your device. However, as suggested by @J Shapiro in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13743956/716216), you could use the following code to listen for the `UIApplicationSuspendedNotification` notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(suspended:) name:@"UIApplicationSuspendedNotification" object:nil];

-(void)suspended:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Suspended");
}
```

Comment: this seems not working with iOS8, any known alternative?