# Detect when user press Cancel - telprompt - objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, tel, telprompt

I have seen this question before but without any real answer.

I am using the following code to start a phone call in objective-c.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt:1234567890"]]
```

This code opens a dialog with the telephone number, an Abort button and a Call button.

Does anyone know how to detect if the Cancel button was pressed?

I need to do some special arrangements in app if Cancel is pressed.

I have tried to use a `UIAlertView` combined with the `@"tel:1234567890"` command, but that isn't any good. If the `"tel:"` command is used, the user will leave the app which isn't what I want...

Thanks!

/Henrik

Comment: Beware that the `telprompt` is not an official url scheme. Apple can remove this scheme in future version of iOS.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743344/how-to-find-out-if-user-pressed-call-or-cancel-button-when-making-call-from-my-a).

Comment: rckoenes - I am aware that the telprompt isn't an official scheme. However, I have seen posts within this topic that says that their apps have been approved by Apple so I hope that they are right ;-)

Comment: Mudit Bajpai - I looked at that post before. It gives a hint when the user completes the call, not when he Cancels it if I am not mistaken. I tried it a while ago...

Comment: @HenrikBengtsson did you find any answer for your query? Please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think is possible to make guess which button user selected in call prompt.

After you call `openURL:` your app receive `[AppDelegate applicationWillResignActive:]` method call.

Then possible two cases:

If user select **Call** you get `[AppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:]` because phone app will open.

If user select **Cancel** you get `[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]` method call.

I think you can implement some singleton to save app state and update it in this methods.

Good luck